# Orientation Sensor Accelerometer for Spirit Level

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, sensors

I am developing a spirit level.
Currently I use the x and y values of the accelerometer.
I do not use the z value.
In general it works, but it isnt very smooth.

Would it be a better solution to use the orientation sensor or maybe both?

Comment: It will largely depend on hardware. Some sensors are better than others, they all have different sampling rates, etc.

Comment: Why not multiply the sensor values by a scaling factor to improve the sensitivity?

Comment: I multiply the values to the account of pixel i need to display them. And I dont think that this improves the sensitivity. I display the raw values and I can see that they change in steps of 0.2 or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that I used was a scaling factor which is what midoalageb suggested. I use a scale factor of 0.5 so essentially the sensor value is cut in half. This makes the jitters less noticeable. This also slows the bubble down a bit so that it doesn't seem like it is jumping from one end to the other when tilting the device.